# Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Tags: php

I got this error message :

[image]

And I already set this on the top of my page

```
    // Display error - if there is 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Did you check your php.ini file (max_execution_time value)?

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0)`. Don't use all caps (in general for ini settings) and use 0 not -1 when setting value to no limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 0).
```

Don't use all caps (in general for ini settings) and use 0 not -1 when setting value to no limit.

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time