# Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in ping ip script

Tags: ip-address, ping

i have problem with my ping ip script because took to long for ping on 40 ip address who have i use to monitoring. this is my script to ping ip :

```
**function checkPing($address){
    if(strtolower(PHP_OS)=='winnt'){
        $command = "ping -n 4 $address";
        exec($command, $output, $status);
    }else{
        $command = "ping -c 1 $address";
        exec($command, $output, $status);
    }
    if($status === 0){
        $value = "Success";
    }else{
        $value =  "failes";
    }
    return $value;
}**
```

is there a faster script to process pings to multiple ip addresses? thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506004/maximum-execution-time-of-300-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: When asking code releated questions, it is always required that you add a tag for the language that you're using to write code. Please [edit] your question to add that tag. You'll also find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.